# What mechanism of language can be used to explain competitive synonyms similar to high-frequency word?

Tags: language-change, frequency

Suppose we have two competitive synonyms **A** and **B**.

We found out that during the historical changes of the language, **A** gains dominant position.
We found out the fact above via a statistical survey of language materials of different periods.

We think the reason that **A** gains dominant position is that there is a high-frequency word **A'** which has a similar form with A.
(And, **A**, **B** and **A'** are roughly identical in meaning. Strict speaking, **A** and **B** are a bit stronger than **A'**.)

Which mechanism can be used to explain this?

I'm thinking of analogical mechanism.

Comment: Could you add some background to this question? Where is it coming from? What kind of "mechanism" do you have in mind?

Comment: @lapropriu I've added my thoughts. I'm not sure what do you mean by 'background'. I've noticed something, and I want to know how to explain it. Is this the 'background'?

Comment: I'm not clear on what your approach is. Is this a question about the organization of entries in the mental lexicon of speakers? Is this about the sociolinguistics of word choice? Or about semantic change (though there doesn't seem to be any semantic change in your very abstract example)? Maybe if you gave some background, like what you were reading that made you think of this, that would make your question clearer. Or some real example where you have 3 words that are identical in meaning (A', A, B), A' is highly frequent, A is similar in form, and A becomes dominant.

Comment: It seems that you're starting with an assumption that there are absolutely equal synonyms. I've never seen two words that are completely equal for all situations. Yes, there are *contexts* where two words can be equal, but there are other contexts where using a certain synonym is preferred or even required.

Comment: @lapropriu Thanks. This is a question about historical changes of language. I've edited my question.

Comment: @bytebuster I've said 'identical in meaning', not absolutely equal. For example, there are no semantic difference between 'you' and 'thou'.

Comment: Semantic difference is huge: "thou" can't be (and never was) used in a plural *context*.

Comment: @bytebuster Sorry, I used a bad example.

Comment: Then you may find a context-free example and add it to your question. If there's no such an example, it might be an answer by itself. :)

Comment: @bytebuster A bad example is still an example. ;-) When used in a singular context, 'thou' and 'you' are competitive synonyms. And 'you' gains dominant position.

Comment: More examples please.